# opposite of filter es2016

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I do below code when I've done removed a user.

```
users.filter(obj => obj.id === user.id);
```

It's wrong because now my users object left one user object, instead I should remove the item from the list base on the id. So I wonder is there any opposite of filter function?

Comment: `users.filter(obj => obj.id !== user.id);`

Comment: `Array.prototype.keep = function (cb) { return this.filter(i => !cb(i)); }`…?

Comment: @deceze Not that `users.keep(obj => obj.id === user.id)` would make much sense semantically mind you…

Answer (score 5):

The opposite of filter is filter. You just need to specify what you want to keep.

For example, if you want odd numbers:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(x => x%2 != 0);
```

if you want the opposite:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].filter(x => x%2 == 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript does not have an opposite function for `filter`, the way some languages like Ruby do (`Array#reject`). As mentioned in other answers you should instead negate the condition in the function being passed to `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

You should just change condition in callback function.

```
users.filter(obj => obj.id !== user.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to opposite a callback function, you can do this:

```
myArray.filter((x,y,z) => !callbackFunction(x,y,z));
```